# Where is Hockaday School 1940 census page?

Tags: united-states, census-records, 1940s, texas, school-records

I'm looking for a student who I believe attended the [Hockaday boarding school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockaday_School) for girls during the 1940 census.  I used http://stevemorse.org/census/unified.html to lookup the [ED number of 255-181](http://stevemorse.org/census/viewer1940.html?state=TX&county=255&ed=181) for Welch Road in Dallas, Texas based on the current address given for the school of [11600 Welch Road, Dallas, Texas](https://www.google.com/maps/place/11600+Welch+Rd,+Dallas,+TX+75229).  I found Welch Road on page 7 of the 30 pages for that ED, but no listing for the school.  I tried searching for Forest Lane which is the only other road to abut the school property today, but it is not listed in the ED search for 1940.

Where can I locate the census records for this school to see the list of all girls that were boarding?

---

Based on Jan Murphy's suggestion, I looked up the school head, [Ela Hockaday b. March 12, 1875](https://tshaonline.org/handbook/online/articles/fho06) and found her in [ED number 255-38](http://stevemorse.org/census/viewer1940.html?state=TX&county=255&ed=38) on page 29 at the address of [5601 Bonita in Dallas](https://www.google.com/maps/place/5601+Bonita+Ave,+Dallas,+TX+75206).  On the prior page, a bunch of employees are listed, but no students are shown on either page 28 or 29.  On page 28, a note says "School Dormitory" at 2407 Greenville Avenue.  Therefore, it appears I need to locate this child with her widowed father on the census somewhere.

Comment: Image #28 is Roll: T627_4173, ED 255-38 Sheet 14B. Can you read the note in the margin opposite line 73 and following?  "Note: No Dwelling Unit on [Belmont?] in ED Block 26" Could that refer to a classroom or adminstrative building?  You can see Belmont two blocks over on the map you linked to.

Comment: P.S. If you haven't already, try searching Hockaday school yearbooks or registers of students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a copy of the [1940 Instructions to Enumerators](https://www.census.gov/history/pdf/1940instructions.pdf) from the US Census Bureau.

Students are discussed on page 16, under **Persons Not to Be Enumerated in Your District:**

> e. Students or children living or boarding with this household in
>   order to attend some school, college, or other education in the
>   locality, but who have a usual place of residence elsewhere from which
>   they will be reported.

However, on the next page, under Enumeration of Special Classes of Persons, paragraph 318 says:

> 318. Students at School or College. -- If there is a school, college, or other educational institution in your district which has students
>        from outside your district, enumerate as residents of the school only
>        those students who have no usual places of residence elsewhere.
>        Especially in a university or professional school, there will be a
>        considerable number of the older students who are not members of any
>        household located elsewhere.  Find and  enumerate all such persons.

My search strategy would be to find a published history of the boarding school that listed the staff at the school.

Paragraph 319:

> **School Teachers.** -- Enumerate teachers  in a school or college at the place where they live while engaged in teaching, even though they
>   may spend the summer vacation at their parents' home or elsewhere.

Another possibility is that the school might have been listed by mistake in the Non-Resident schedules.  Check for any sheets numbered 81 or higher.

If you haven't already, check newspapers and published histories to make sure the school wasn't in another location on Census Day in 1940.